# Default configuration parameters for boxfuse

Tags: cloudcaptain

Is there a documented list of configuration Boxfuse parameters that can be used in boxfuse.conf?
Mainly, when you create and configure an application in web console, I would like to assign that application to concrete project through .conf instead of Boxfuse creating another app during deployment because if inferred it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the name of the boxfuse.conf property in the second column of the manual pages. See for example: https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/commandline/run